# basic delay on jquery .click function

Tags: jquery, timedelay

I have the most basic jquery function of them all, but I couldn't find a way in the documentation to trigger the contents of this click function after say 1500 milliseconds:

```
$('.masonryRecall').click(function(){
  $('#mainContent').masonry();
 });
```

P.S. just noticed the .delay function jquery 1.4, although, I am using version 1.3. I don't know whether updating this would interfere with any of the other javascript I currently have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it with regular javascript using [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

```
$('.masonryRecall').click(function(){
        setTimeout("$('#mainContent').masonry()", 1500);
    });
```

Comment: @Bryon Whitlock Thanks for that. Just to add its .masonry(). But also the timeout doesn't seem to be working. it still fires immediately???

Comment: Again thanks for the direction. just another minor alteration and it works perfectly: setTimeout("$('#mainContent').masonry()", 1500);

Comment: Don't use quotes around the function. That's equivalent to using eval(). You should instead wrap it in an anonymous function, or use [jQuery's proxy function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221163/way-to-execute-jquery-member-functions-inside-settimeout-without-closure).

Answer (score 16):

You should generally stay away from string literals in setTimeout/setInterval. Instead use a closure:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#mainContent').masonry(); }, 1500);`
```

and even better use it like this (note: the outer closure isn't really necessary):

```
(function($){
    var timeout=null;
    $('.masonryRecall').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout=setTimeout(function(){$('#mainContent').masonry();}, 1500);
    });
}(jQuery));
```