# Way to execute jQuery member functions inside setTimeout without closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, settimeout

I was trying to do something along these lines:

```
setTimeout($('#element').hide,3000);
```

which seems simple enough, but it is crippled by the ["this" problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem).  I want to find a way to just pass the actual function as a parameter, *without wrapping it in another function*, e.g. I do not want to do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#element').hide();},3000);
```

What I've tried:

```
setTimeout($('#element').hide,3000);
setTimeout($('#element').hide.apply(document),3000);   /* jQuery docs say that document is the default context */
setTimeout($('#element',document).hide,3000);
setTimeout($(document).find('#element').hide,3000);
setTimeout($(window).find('#element').hide,3000);
setTimeout($.proxy($('#element').hide,document),3000); /* I know this returns a function, which I don't want, but I have tried it */
setTimeout(($('#element').hide()),3000);               /* functional expression */
```

I'm looking for the way to remedy this problem, but I don't want to wrap it in another function.  The less lines of code, the better.  I know WHY this isn't working as expected, but HOW can I fix it without wrapping it in a closure?

Comment: setTimeout will only take a function name, or anonymous function as a parameter, so I don't think this can be done as you want. What is your reason for not wanting to use an anonymous function?

Comment: In the article you gave us, they give a possible solution. Why don't you try it ?

Comment: @epascarello Those are what I've tried. Seven different attempts at a single line of code.

Comment: Just wrap it in an anonymous function (or define a wrapper function just before the `setTimeout`, and pass that function to `setTimeout`). So much cleaner than any of these other options. (Although if I had to pick one of them, it would probably be `$.proxy`. But... Just. Use. The. Anonymous. Function. (or explain why not...) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way by binding the context of the method with the element itself so that in jquery hide method `this` will point to jquery object and not global context. You can create bound functions using:

[Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Cross Browser Alternative for this:

[$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Ex:

```
var $elem = $('#element');
setTimeout($elem.hide.bind($elem),3000);
```

or

```
setTimeout($.proxy($elem.hide, $elem),3000);
```

or

```
setTimeout($.fn.hide.bind($elem),3000); //setTimeout($.proxy($.fn.hide, $elem),3000);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfem8/)**

Comment: nice. if you are re-binding anyway - you could use $.fn.hide rather than $elem.hide

Comment: `setTimeout($.proxy($.fn.hide, $('#element')))` is shorter.

Comment: I really like your fiddle because it's a one-liner without a variable, but I'm confused about why .`bind()` is allowing you to pass a jQuery object? [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) says the first parameter should be a string.

Comment: @AlexW I am not using jquery.bind it is [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), jquery bind is for attaching events. Equivalent for function.bind is jquery.proxy. It bind a context to a function reference, so that when invoked it will have `this` context as that of the context set. It is also called Bound Functions